# I have a background image. Padding of a box from top pushes image down, how can i avoid this?

Tags: css

I created a  
There is a background image in this header
inside I put an image link

so now there is an image in the header. So I try to position the header.
But when I try to position the header with a padding, say from the top of 300px it gets the image to the place I want  but the problem is that the background image grows 300px bigger downwards.
how do i prevent this from happening :(?

Comment: Simple code sample will help to help you!

Comment: And maybe posting a link to a working example using something like http://jsfiddle.net/ will help too.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code I am not quite sure how everything is laid out, but I think you can solve the problem one of two ways:
1.) Use margin on the header instead of padding to position it
 2.) Set a static height for the background and any time you add padding to the header, reduce the height of the background by the same amount.

If i am understanding you correctly, one of those should fix your problem.